# Pourquoi « quinze jours d'attentes » avec un « s » à la fin ?

Tags: orthographe, pluriel, indications-de-temps

Je me demande pourquoi on met un *s* à la fin de *attente* dans « 15 jours d'attentes » ?

Comment: Hum, personnellement, je ne mets pas de `s` à `attente` dans cet exemple... Est-ce une erreur ? Où as-tu vu cet orthographe s'il te plaît ?

Comment: partout dans les forums

Comment: En général sur les forums, les internautes écrivent vite et mal.

Comment: Chaque fois que tu te fies à l’orthographe sur les forums, Dieu tue un chaton.

Comment: Je vois un cas extrêmement spécifique qui pourrait justifier cette orthographe : « quinze jours pendants lesquels mes attentes grandissaient ». Mais sur « les forums » c'est à coup sûr une faute d'orthographe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je pense que la source d'où vient cette version écrite *d'attente* avec un *s* n'est pas fiable.

> 3 heures d'attente

ou

> 15 jours d'attente

s'écrivent sans *s*.

Le Petit Larousse donne d'ailleurs un exemple [ici](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/attente/6244).